# Logics in Postgres plain queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make query in Postgres that inserts new item if existing data has invalid data. I want to do something like this

```sql
if not exists( select * from table where field='value ) then
    insert into ...
end if;
```

Can I do this without functions?

**UPD**
Here's the table

```sql
create table if not exists test_md (
    id          serial  not null,
    partition   text    not null,
    version     int     not null,
    data        jsonb   not null,
    
    primary key (partition, version)
);
```

Here's some data

```sql
insert into test_md(partition, version, data) 
values
    ('part one', 1, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}')
    ('part one', 2, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}')
    ('part two', 4, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}')
    ('part two', 5, '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}')
;
```

For example I want to insert data set

```json
{
    'partition': 'part one', 
    'data':      '{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}'
}
```

I should do nothing if `partition` and `data` are the same with the `v2` record. In any other case I should add a new record with version `max + 1`.

Comment: `insert ... on conflict (field) do nothing`

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you meman by *if existing data has invalid data*.

Comment: There is no `if`, there only is `where`: So: `insert into ... WHERE not exists( select * from table where field='value );` BTW: there are no functions in your code fragment, either.